# Android notification setFullScreenIntent action button unwanted border on Android 11

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-11

When showing notifications on Android 11 having `setFullScreenIntent`, action button in the notification gets an annoying border:

[image: Notification on Android 11]

While running same code on Android 10 or when removing `setFullScreenIntent` on Android 11, notification design will be material as intended:

[image: Notification on Android 10 or without setFullScreenIntent]

My code for reference:

```
    private void showNotification() {
        NotificationManager androidNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        createHeadsUpNotificationChannel(androidNotificationManager);

        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.layout_sample_notif);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.id1, "Header");
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.id2, "Body");

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL);
        builder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setContentTitle("Sample Notification")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sample_icon)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
            .setCustomContentView(contentView)
            .setGroup(GROUP_KEY)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM).setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL);

        Intent fullScreenIntent = new Intent(this, FullscreenActivity.class);
        fullScreenIntent.setAction(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        fullScreenIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        PendingIntent fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            fullScreenIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true);

        Intent dismissIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        dismissIntent.setAction("action_dismiss");
        builder.setOngoing(true)
            .addAction(R.drawable.sample_icon,
                "Dismiss",
                PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, dismissIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT));

        androidNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }

    private void createHeadsUpNotificationChannel(NotificationManager androidNotificationManager) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL,
            "Sample Channel",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setDescription("Sample Desc");
        channel.enableLights(false);
        channel.enableVibration(false);
        androidNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

I need help having a consistent material design for my notification.

Comment: The answer probably is to also align that `RemoteViews` to the center.

Comment: Your code does not match your screenshots. Moreover, how notifications and their actions get rendered is up to the platform, not you or me. The behavior can vary by OS version, such as [the upcoming Android 12 changes that will affect notifications like this one](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#custom-notifications). The behavior can vary by manufacturer as well, as manufacturers are welcome to modify how the notification shade renders notifications.

Comment: @CommonsWare code-screenshot mismatch was for hiding unnecessary details just to focus one the issue. Do you mean that it is recommended to let the OS decide the proper design based on the case? That makes sense to me, although I'm still curious to know if there's a way to enforce material design for the action button.

Comment: "Do you mean that it is recommended to let the OS decide the proper design based on the case?" -- it is not so much "recommended" as "you do not have a choice". A `Notification` object is a request for how it should look, but individual devices can interpret that request in different ways.